# Вывод значения переменной WIN API

Tags: c++, winapi

Как вывести значение переменой в WIN API

```
int i = 5;
TCHAR text[256];
_stprintf(text, TEXT("%d"), i);
TextOut(hdc, 700, 50, text,100);
```

Не выводит ничего, в дебаге строка работает все конвертирует, а вывода нету(

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, возможно проблема в том, что Вы установили количество символов в 100, а не в `strlen(text)`

```
int i=5;
char text[50]={'\0'};//можно ещё обнулить, для уверенности
itoa(i,text,10);//переводим число в строку
TextOutA(hdc,10,10,text,strlen(text));
```

Напомню, что в `WM_PAINT` `HDC` получаем функцией `BeginPaint(HWND,LPPAINTSTRUCT)`, освобождаем `EndPaint(HWND,LPPAINTSTRUCT)`. Во всех остальных случаях - `GetDC(HWND)`\ `GetWindowDC(HWND)`, освобождаем `ReleaseDC(HWND,HDC)`

Answer (score 0):

Нужны скобки (`BeginPath` и `EndPath`) и, возможно, нужно установить цвет (`SetTextColor` и `SetBkMode`), чтобы не писать чёрным по чёрному.

```
BeginPath(hdc);
// SetTextColor(hdc, ...); 
// SetBkMode(hdc, ...); 
TextOut(hdc, 700, 50, text,100);
EndPath(hdc);
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогает

Comment: @user207044 А цвет вы попробовали сменить, как посоветовал отвечающий?

Comment: Да установил черный цвет, не помогло

Comment: @user207044 а, например, прямоугольник нарисовать удаётся? А то подозрение такое, что с `hdc` неверное обращаетесь. Покажите больше кода вокруг.